# continue a while loop if a condition is true

Tags: java

I have a guessing game program in which you have 4 attempts to guess a number between 0 and 9. I want to add an option where the program asks the user if they want to play again when the user exceeds his 4 attempts. This is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int nb, x;
    int count = 1;
    Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
    nb = (int) (Math.random() * 10);

    System.out.print("Guess the number between 0 and 9 (4 Guesses allowed):");
    x = inp.nextInt();

    while (x != nb) {
        if (count <= 3) {
            if (x > nb) System.out.println("Lesser");
            else if (x < nb) System.out.println("Bigger");
            System.out.println("Wrong try another number");
            x = inp.nextInt();
            if (x == nb) System.out.println("Found!!");
        } else {
            System.out.print("you exceeded your allowed Guesses");
            break;
        }
        count++;
    }
    inp.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with just a minor tweak this will get you going.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
int nb, x=-1;
int count = 0;
Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
nb = (int) (Math.random() * 10);


while (x != nb) {
    System.out.print("Guess the number between 0 and 9 (4 Guesses allowed):");
    x = inp.nextInt();
        inp.nextLine();
         count++;
    if (x == nb){ System.out.println("Found!!");break;}
    if (x > nb) System.out.println("Lesser");
        else if (x < nb) System.out.println("Bigger");
        System.out.println("Wrong try another number");

    if (count == 2) {


        System.out.println("you exceeded your allowed Guesses");
        System.out.println("would you like to play again? (input y or n)");
        String newGame = inp.next();
               inp.nextLine();

        if(newGame.compareTo("n")==0)break;
        else count = 0;  

    }

}
inp.close();
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you , this code is exactly what i was looking for but i just need a few more tweaks, when the loop closes at the break i want to let the user know that the game is over , how can i do that ?

Comment: so, just after inp.close() add a system print.  Please accept answer if this is working for you.  Also, you may want to change the if(newGame.compareTO...  If the answer is 0 you may want to print you lost and then System.exit() to kill the program.

Answer (score 2):

hope you (and everyone else) are staying healthy!

Nested in your while loop, you have an if-else statement. Here is where I suggest you make an addition. Inside the else branch, I would output your desired message, and then handle user input: if the user says yes, reset your count integer to zero; the while loop will restart and you will be able to continue guessing. If the user says no, I would execute the break statement just as you do right now. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for checking in hope your and everyone here are staying safe in those difficult times, your answer was helpful but some one here posted a similar idea with the code on display so it was what i needed, thank you though for your input. Stay safe

Comment: of course! keep coding @samerg :) also, make sure to accept the solution you feel solves the problem (click the checkmark under the arrows). it's important in terms of marking the issue as resolved, and it rewards the user who answered your question!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a good candidate to make use of separate methods with. Move your current loop to another method, then make another loop inside your main method that calls your newly made method and prompts for a replay when the player returns after that run.

Partial code example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
  boolean play = true;
  while(play) {
    runGame(inp);
    System.out.println("Play again?");
    play = inp.nextLine().toUpperCase().contains("YES");
  }
  inp.close();
}

public static void runGame(Scanner inp) {
  int count = 1;
  //Move your current loop stuff here
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your input , i tried your code for knowledge purposes but your way is more advanced than i wanted but i always appreciate new ideas and ways to write programs so thank you for sharing. Stay Safe

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution

At the end of your control flow, either where you **guess the correct answer** or you **exceed the number of guesses**, you need to prompt the user for an input.

Perhaps something along the lines of: "Do you wish to try again?"

You can do this using the scanner library, you can read about it and implement it from [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).

If they type **"yes"** (beware of case)

Assign `nb = (int) (Math.random() * 10);` again and validate it's not the same value as previously. This will cause the loop to keep running and thus the game continues.

**Note:** It is important that if the same number appears again you handle it so to not terminate the game. You can do this by getting another random number != to the previous one, or excluding that previous number from your random number pool so the selection is guaranteed to be different.

Additionally, I would advise you to give your variables a better name for readability, and formatting your code better, for the same reason.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the solution , i did find a more clearer one but nonetheless  your advice is well received i will come up with better names for the variables to make it more understandable and better. Stay Safe

Comment: You too, and happy to help

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    final int min = 0;
    final int max = 10;
    final int maxGuesses = 4;

    try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        while (true) {
            final int expected = min + new Random().nextInt(max + 1 - min);
            boolean found = false;

            System.out.printf("Guess the number between %d and %d (%d Guesses allowed).\n", min, max, maxGuesses);

            for (int i = 1; i <= maxGuesses; i++) {
                System.out.printf("Guess #%d: ", i);
                int number = scan.nextInt();

                if (number == expected) {
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }

                System.out.println(number > expected ? "Lesser" : "Bigger");

                if (i < maxGuesses)
                    System.out.println("Wrong try another number");
            }

            System.out.println(found ? "Found!!" : "you exceeded your allowed Guesses");

            System.out.print("Do you want to continue (Y/N): ");
            char ch = scan.next().charAt(0);

            if (Character.toLowerCase(ch) == 'N')
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your input i always like learning new ways and new codes , this works but not what i was looking for though i appreciate it for learning purposes , Stay Safe